# Call a CheckBox's Text to a MessageBox?

Tags: c#, checkbox, messagebox

Hello I'm having trouble trying to get this part of my code working:

```
 private void selectedBox(string text)
    {
        var boxes = new Control[] { f1.checkEdit7, f1.checkEdit8, f1.checkEdit9 };
        foreach (var box in boxes)
        {
            if(box.Checked == true)
            {
                text = box.Text.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to get the selected checkbox's text and call it in a MessageBox, how would I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to do an evaluated compare against a boolean because it's already a boolean (eg `if (box.Checked == true)` is the same as `if (box.Checked)`.  The second one is shorter and easier to read.  Kudos on the question, you've given what you want to happen and your example is good.  However, the code looks like it should work, so it's best to describe what the problem is, and if there is an exception, provide the exception type, the message, and what line threw the exception.

Comment: voids don't return anything.  It looks like you are expecting the "text" variable to be ref by default.

Comment: Hello @Erik Philips, thank you for the tip! The error I am receiving is on the line `if (box.Checked)` the `Checked` is underlined in red stating "'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no accessible extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: If you have an array of CheckBoxes why do you declare an array of Controls?

Comment: @xJuiced I highly recommend that if someone asks a question, you should actually update the question itself and not response via comment so that future reads do not need to read the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  private List<string> selectedBoxes()
    {
        List<string> checkBoxText = new List<string>();
        var boxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3 };
        foreach (var box in boxes)
        {
            if (box.Checked == true)
            {
                checkBoxText.Add(box.Text);

            }
        }
        return checkBoxText;
    }
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
        var selectedCheckboxes = selectedBoxes();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", selectedCheckboxes));
    }
```

The biggest change was using the more specific Checkbox class which inherits from Checkbox -> ButtonBase => control. With the more specific class you get functionality geared towards checkboxes instead of controls in general.

Comment: Well, this works of course, but I think you should try to explain what is the problem and  why the OP version cannot work

Comment: This did work for me although I had to change `var boxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3 };` to `var boxes = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckEdit[] { f1.checkEdit1, f1.checkEdit2, f1.checkEdit3 };` because my checkboxes were from DevExpress.

Comment: When you use an array of controls to store your specific type of control you still have an array containing your specific type (none changes them to something lesser) but when you loop over the array of Control the returned variable in the foreach statement is of type Control (the base class) so you cannot use the Checked specific property. If you do an explicit cast onto the box variable to be a CheckEdit then you get back access to the Checked property

Comment: the casting would look like this  if (((CheckEdit)box).Checked == true)